# Run test with Testcafe + Teamcity + Browserstack

Tags: automated-tests, teamcity, e2e-testing, browserstack, testcafe

Does anyone be able to successfully set up the testing by using all these 3 tools?

I can run testcafe test alone at the server and it takes 20 sec to run.

When I run that test with TeamCity, it takes 12Min.

When I add browserstack, somehow browserstack local get in the process and it fails.

Also, I used this Git and try to make it work, their repo does not work as well.

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack

So does anyone know how these 3 can work together?

- TeamCity Professional 10.0.1 (build 42078)
- npm versioin 5.6.0
- node version 8.9.4
- testcafe version 1.0.0

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause of the issue based only on this information. I can only recommend you follow steps, which can probably help you solve the issue.

1) Doesn't TestCafe work with a specified test or with any test? Try to run only one simple test (empty or only with the click action) with TeamCity. Does it pass? If it does not, I would appreciate it if you share this test code with us.
2) Try to run your test only in one browser. Does the issue still occur?
3) Run the `testcafe` command with the `-b` argument. Does it return anything?

Comment: 4) Connect to TeamCity via RDP and run TestCafe via the command line command. Does it work?
5) Run browsers via the TeamCity build step command without TestCafe. Was it possible to start browsers without TestCafe?
6) Share your generated TestCafe report.
7) Share your command line arguments.
8) Try the `--skip-js-errors` option.

Comment: When i try command line on TeamCity server it runs all test on chrome / firefox / browserstack . But when i run same command on Teamcity chrome does not launch. Firefox run successfully and BrowserStack give Local.js error which says "Disconnected".  tescafe -b return local browsers. testcafe -b browserstack returns all browserstack browsers.